# ASP.NET MVC, After rebuilding the solution, I get Parser Error(Server Error in '/' Application.) in Source File: /global.asax?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, unit-testing, debugging

I am new in ASP.NET MVC. I have got a full project, trying to learn the projects functionality by test, comment and uncommenting the code, but here build and rebuild are confusing me.

When I test the project by building solution with zero error build I would get no error and also when I comment one or some line of code to test the functionality of project in MVC(By Building) and test the page it works despite some building error.

In rebuilding case, when some line of codes are commented then rebuilding the solution getting the :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'ProjectName.Web.NameApplication'.
Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs"
Inherits="ProjectName.Web.NameApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

This is really very confusing for example:
In the solution there is a project:

`ProjectName.Core>>DataAccess(folder)` inside the folder there are 20 classes like:

```
Daytaaccess>>DefaultStrategy.cs,DefaultStrategy,ExpressionValuePair,IDataAction.cs,IDataMod
el, IDataStrategy,IPropertyValuePair,IRepository,ISortation,ITransaction, 
IUnitOfWork , IUnitOfWorkFactory,PropertyValuePair.cs
```

By uncommenting all the classes the project still works except `"PropertyValuePair.cs"` but 
when I uncomment the `PropertyValuePair.cs` project won't work except uncommenting all the 
previously commented classes.

I think the issue is on Visual Studio Caching, not caching the commented code
I have also tried commenting a table's  entire class, in browser the pages still works
and table's data still gets updated.

If it is so, how to remove caching in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: without seeing what's actual source commented or not, it's hard to reason what's going on.  Doing a build only compiles and links the code.  Sounds like your class PropertyValuePair has a depedency on the all the other classes if it only compiles when all of them are uncommented.

Comment: It looks there is cache problem, Even if I comment a table name in codes it still shows on browser and gets updated in database as well. what could be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a caching problem. Visual studio does not cache builds. If there are multiple projects in the solution, there is a chance you are not building all of them, and that the MVC project is using previously-built dll's.

A better way to investigate code is to set breakpoints and debug. I wouldn't try commenting out code and re-running. That won't really teach you anything.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am also batch-building the solution in order to make sure all the projects are built.  

After setting the breakpoints then... I really do not know how to best investigate the project, there are 100s classes and 1000s(Thousands) line of codes.

Comment: What are your goals for this project investigation? Why are you investigating it?

Comment: I am trying to create a project based on this open source project, to do so I have to analyze and understand all the codes(in MVC where I am new) I have web form background.

Lets say in the current project admin only can post, user can comment.
But I would like to continue to make it like stackoverflow.com where user can post, edit and delete their posts.

Comment: In that case, you will have to become intimately familiar with the 100's of classes and 1000's of lines of code anyway. My suggestion is to get started with a couple of MVC books. I like Steve Sanderson's.

Comment: [MVC3 in Action](https://bitbucket.org/jeffreypalermo/mvc-3-in-action/wiki/Home) is pretty good as well